# Listing something as table with one column

Tags: tables, lists, best-practices

This is more a question on general design of something than a technical question. I want to list parameters that are used in a model. Since I have 7 parameters I think it wouldn't be readable if I list them in plain text like: p1,p2,p2 ... p7. 
That's why I want to either choose a list or table. I think a standart list like

- p1
- p2
- p3

  ...
- p7 
  would not be the best choice for displaying single parameters. 
  In my opinion it would look more compact as a table. But  I am not sure if it is bad practice to use a table with just one column.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried both ways. Your non-existent MWE gives no indication of what you might have done, if anything.

Try this:

```
% onecoltableprob.tex  SE 644775

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum\[3\]

%\lipsum\[3\]
\begin{itemize}
\item p1
\item p2
\item p3
\item ...
\item p7
\end{itemize}

\lipsum\[3\]

\begin{table}\[h\]
  \centering
  \caption{A table}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    p1 \\
  p2 \\
  p3 \\
  ... \\
  p7
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum\[3\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It all depends on how you want your document to appear. The above gives some indication of how your parameter listing might appear among general text. It is your decision as to how you think your document looks best overall.

For me, if it is just a list of two characters then the enumerate looks better than the table, but if the entries are longer then table might be the way to go.